# DSE Servers not found and unable to initialize hash chunk service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

I'm following this opendedup guide from github (https://github.com/opendedup/sdfs).
However, I'm stucked at the DSE server part whereby need to mount a volume. Anybody can guide me through solving the problem?

Below shows the problem that I'm currently encountering:

```
dsi@dsi-VirtualBox:~$ sudo mount.sdfs pool_5 /media/pool0
dsi@dsi-VirtualBox:~$ Running Program SDFS Version 3.1.9
reading config file = /etc/sdfs/pool_5-volume-cfg.xml
Jun 06, 2016 8:08:36 PM org.jgroups.stack.Configurator resolveAndAssignField
WARNING: JGRP000014: TP.loopback has been deprecated: enabled by default
Jun 06, 2016 8:08:36 PM org.jgroups.stack.Configurator resolveAndAssignField
WARNING: JGRP000014: Discovery.timeout has been deprecated: GMS.join_timeout should be used instead
Jun 06, 2016 8:08:36 PM org.jgroups.stack.Configurator resolveAndAssignField
WARNING: JGRP000014: Discovery.num_initial_members has been deprecated: will be ignored

-------------------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address=dsi-VirtualBox-16674, cluster=sdfs-cluster, physical address=10.0.2.15:42371
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Unable to initialize HashChunkService
java.io.IOException: No DSE Servers found
    at org.opendedup.sdfs.cluster.DSEClientSocket.start(DSEClientSocket.java:113)
    at org.opendedup.sdfs.cluster.DSEClientSocket.<init>(DSEClientSocket.java:86)
    at org.opendedup.sdfs.servers.HCServiceProxy.init(HCServiceProxy.java:178)
    at org.opendedup.sdfs.servers.SDFSService.start(SDFSService.java:58)
    at fuse.SDFS.MountSDFS.setup(MountSDFS.java:203)
    at fuse.SDFS.MountSDFS.init(MountSDFS.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:207)
Service exit with a return value of 255
```

Thank you.